# CUrl, Pecl HTTPRequest, file_get_contents() NOTHING WORKS

Tags: stack, httprequest, file-get-contents, forever

Maybe I just have another bad day, but I've tried all of the possible ways to send GET Request with Cookies and every single one gets stacked. My page is just reloading forever.

my $url = "http://localhost/content-search/demo/"

first attempt to use class HTTPRequest from Pecl... I deleted it,

but here are my attempts to send it with curl:

```php
public static function sendRequest($url, array $cookies) {
    $c = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $page = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
    return $page;
}
```

And with file_get_contents:

```php
public static function sendRequest($url, $cookies)
{
    if(is_array($cookies)) {
        $cookies = self::formatCookies($cookies);
    }

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'header' => 'Connection: close\r\nCookie: ' . $cookies
        )
    );
    return file_get_contents($url, NULL, stream_context_create($options));
}
```

again, they all three get stacked and the request is being sent like forever.

Comment: ok, I found out, that when I remove cookies from cUrl it works fine.

Comment: And the problem is with that cookie: PHPSESSID=2nfugeima54jgccce7n8d86cu7

may I ask why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved!

problem was in cookies.
the **session_write_close();** solves the problem :)